# How to convert QMenu to QMenuBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have `QMenu`, which contains submenus:

```
QMenu menu;
// Add some submenus
menu.addMenu(new QMenu("1", menu));
menu.addMenu(new QMenu("2", menu));
menu.addMenu(new QMenu("3", menu));
```

I want to move these submenus from `QMenu` to `QMenuBar`:

```
QMenuBar* menubar = convertFromQMenu(&menu);
```

Here is how I think the implementation of `convertFromQMenu` might look like:

```
QMenuBar* convertFromQMenu(QMenu* menu) {
    QMenuBar *menubar = new QMenuBar();
    /*
    for(QMenu* menu: menu->menus()) {
        menu.setParent(menubar);
        menubar.addMenu(menu);
    }
    */

    return menubar;
}
```

However, the commented code does not compile.

How to fix this?

Comment: What does it mean to convert QMenu to QMenuBar ?, a QMenu can be part of QMenuBar, could you explain better what you want to obtain, maybe an image helps

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that kind of 'conversion'. If you read carefully from the Qt official [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#details) about QMenuBar and addMenu() member, you can easily add your QMenu to your QMenuBar:

```
QMenu menu;
// Add some menus
menu.add (new QMenu("1", menu));
menu.add (new QMenu("2", menu));
menu.add (new QMenu("3", menu));

QMenuBar menubar;
menubar.addMenu(&menu);
```

If you want to use the QMainWindow menu bar, the doc states :

> In most main window style applications you would use the menuBar() function provided in QMainWindow, adding QMenus to the menu bar and adding QActions to the pop-up menus.
>
> Example (from the Menus example):
>
> `fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));`
>
> `fileMenu->addAction(newAct);`

Comment: But in menubar I will have one menu, which popup to "1", "2", "3" menus. That is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

> `for(QMenu* menu: menu->menus()) {`

`QMenu` does not have a `menus` method.

## Solution

The path to get to where you want is a little bit longer:

1. Use [QWidget::actions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#actions) to get a list of the actions, added to the menu
2. Get the `QMenu` associated with each action using [QAction::menu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#menu)

Now you can add the menu to the `QMenuBar`.

**Note:** Do not change the parenting of the menus and submenus.

## Example

Based on your code, I would suggest you to implement `convertFromQMenu` like this:

```
QMenuBar *MainWindow::convertFromQMenu(QMenu *menu)
{
    auto *menubar = new QMenuBar(this);

    foreach (QAction *act, menu->actions())
        if (act->menu())
            menubar->addMenu(act->menu());

    menu->deleteLater();

    return menubar;
}
```

Here is how to test the suggested implementation:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *menu = new QMenu("Menu", this);

    // Add some menus
    menu->addMenu(new QMenu("Menu 1", this));
    menu->addMenu(new QMenu("Menu 2", this));
    menu->addSeparator();

    auto *submenu = new QMenu("Menu 3", this);

    submenu->addActions(QList<QAction *>({new QAction("Action 1", this),
                                          new QAction("Action 2", this),
                                          new QAction("Action 3", this)}));

    menu->addMenu(submenu);

    setMenuBar(convertFromQMenu(menu));
    setCentralWidget(new QWidget(this));
    resize(300, 200);
}
```

I took the liberty to extend this example to switch between *compact* and *extended* form of the menus in the menu bar (not shown here). The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-MenuToBar).

## Result

As written, the given example produces the following result:

[image: Window with the menu expanded to three menus]